# Selecting all sibling tds on right of the clicked Td using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

The target is to Assign a class to all the Tds on the right side of the selected td in an HTML table (using jQuery).

for example if there are total 5 columns (td) and 2nd td is selected, then column 3,4,5 should be assigned a specific class. following code has been tried which only assigns the class to the Immidiate right td and not the proceeding ones..

```
$(this).parent('td').addClass("CheckMark");
$(this).parent('td').next('td').addClass("Green");
```

Any Help will be appreciated.
Kind regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code :

```
$(this).parent('td').nextAll().addClass("Green");
```

Comment: wont this apply the CSS class to the table

Comment: $("td",$(this).parent().parent()).css("background-color","yellow");  It would apply to the entire row.

Comment: but the class only needs to be assigned to the tds on the right side of the clicked td

Comment: the above provided code seems to be working :) how to mark as answer.